# How do I add new class to my project in Visual C++ 6

Tags: visual-c++

I want to add a new class to my Visual C++ 6 project using Class Wizard. I don't want this class to inherit from anything. My class has a function to accept input as integer, and process it

The Class Wizard requires me to add a base class and a DialogID . Which one of the base classes and dialog ID shoud I select? I'm a C# developer and find it really annoying. Should I mannually add my class? How do i do it in Visual C++ 6

Comment: Um. Don't use Class Wizard (which is for creating visual dialogs and is why it wants a `dialog id`)? Look at the other options available in File->New or Project->Add (don't remember exactly what they're called - VC++6 is ancient).

Comment: Got it. Thanks Ken. I'm adding it using Project->Add

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, so it might be useful to others sometime. :-)

Comment: You can always just type `class MyNewClassName { };` in any of your source code files.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, there's always that, too. :-) If, that is, you don't want the class to be usable in other places besides the current source file. If it needs to be used in several places, it should be separated into it's own source file (with a header file too).

Comment: @Ken: "any source code file" includes headers too.

Comment: @Ben: I know. I was referring to separating into a separate .cpp/.hpp file rather than typing into the current source file. Didn't mean you needed to do it separately. Bad phrasing, I guess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Class Wizard` (which is for creating visual dialogs and is why it wants a dialog id).

Use `Project->Add` from the menu. There are several other types of things you can add to your project that don't involve visual dialogs, like header (`.h`) and source code (`.cpp`) files.